# Bug with finite sympy segments

Tags: geometry, linear-algebra, sympy

I am intersecting a plane with 12 segments which represent the edges of a cube. The problem I have is that all the intersections produce one point, even if the point should not be part of the segment, because they should be finite, right?

Code:

```py
from sympy import Point3D, Plane, intersection, Segment3D

# Cube's vertices
v = (Point3D(500, 500, 500), Point3D(-500, 500, 500), Point3D(-500, -500, 500),
     Point3D(500, -500, 500), Point3D(500, 500, -500), Point3D(-500, 500, -500),
     Point3D(-500, -500, -500), Point3D(500, -500, -500))
# Cube´s edges
a = (Segment3D(v[0], v[1]), Segment3D(v[1], v[2]),
     Segment3D(v[2], v[3]), Segment3D(v[3], v[0]),
     Segment3D(v[0], v[4]), Segment3D(v[1], v[5]),
     Segment3D(v[2], v[6]), Segment3D(v[3], v[7]),
     Segment3D(v[4], v[5]), Segment3D(v[5], v[6]),
     Segment3D(v[6], v[7]), Segment3D(v[7], v[4]))

# Example plane which should generate 3 points
plano = Plane(Point3D(450, 400, 400), Point3D(400, 450, 400), Point3D(400, 400, 450))

bad = []
good = []
for i in range(12):
    inter = intersection(plano, a[i])
    # This should be executed when the intersection generates anything, but is always executed:
    if inter:
        bad.append(inter[0])
        # This comparation should not be necessary, checks if point is in range desired
        if abs(inter[0][0]) <= 500 and abs(inter[0][1]) <= 500 and abs(inter[0][2]) <= 500: 
            good.append(inter[0])

print(len(bad), bad)
print(len(good), good)
```

Output:

```
12 [Point3D(250, 500, 500), Point3D(-500, 1250, 500), Point3D(1250, -500, 500), Point3D(500, 250, 500), Point3D(500, 500, 250), Point3D(-500, 500, 1250), Point3D(-500, -500, 2250), Point3D(500, -500, 1250), Point3D(1250, 500, -500), Point3D(-500, 2250, -500), Point3D(2250, -500, -500), Point3D(500, 1250, -500)]
3 [Point3D(250, 500, 500), Point3D(500, 250, 500), Point3D(500, 500, 250)]
```

9 of the 12 points are not part of any segment

Comment: This was a known bug, reported at https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/15069, and fixed back in April.  I have no idea what release version of simpy will contain the fix.

Comment: @jasonharper True, I did not search at github, my bad. I found this: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16637 . It should be fixed at 1.5, which is under development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed on SymPy master but the fix is not yet in a released version. On master I get:

```
3 [Point3D(250, 500, 500), Point3D(500, 250, 500), Point3D(500, 500, 250)]
3 [Point3D(250, 500, 500), Point3D(500, 250, 500), Point3D(500, 500, 250)]
```

(which I assume is what you expect)

Comment: Which version is the master package at? Yes, that is the desired result.

Comment: The next release will be 1.5

Comment: Oh I did not think I could test the current master version directly, now It works fine

Answer (score 0):

This is currently a bug (In sympy 1.4 or early) and will be fixed at 1.5 release.
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/16637